# Position a php Dropdown in a html table

Tags: html, dropdown

Hi so i need to move my drop down (at the top right) to the next slot next to the manufacturer, I currently have a  for it but idk how to get it to post there anything will help, I appreciate any help :)

```
    <form action="SubmitProduct.php" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="Name" required /><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Desription</td><td><input type="text" name="Product_Desription" required /><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Price</td><td><input type="text" name="ProductPrice" required /><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Image</td><td><input type="text" name="ProductImage" required /><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Manufacturer</td><td><input type="" name="" required /><br></td>
    </tr>

<?php 
    include 'db_connection.php';

    $conn = OpenCon();

    echo "Connected Successfully";



    $query = "SELECT * FROM Manufacturer WHERE 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


    echo '<select name="dropdown" style="width:150px;">';

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<option value="'.$r['ManufacturerName'].'">'.$r['ManufacturerName'].'</option>'; 
    }

    echo '</select>';
?>
```

[Image of Webpage layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx1t0.png)

Comment: The select is not within a tr/td block, so it's going to look weird.

Comment: oh right aha, thank you :D @aynber

Comment: There is no such thing as a "php dropdown".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to replace your text-input or add it next to it so if you want to replace it you just need to replace your input in the second column of your manufacturer row with your PHP code.

```
        <form action="SubmitProduct.php" method="post">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="Name" required /><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Desription</td><td><input type="text" name="Product_Desription" required /><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Price</td><td><input type="text" name="ProductPrice" required /><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Image</td><td><input type="text" name="ProductImage" required /><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Manufacturer</td><td>
    <?php 
        include 'db_connection.php';

        $conn = OpenCon();

        echo "Connected Successfully";



        $query = "SELECT * FROM Manufacturer WHERE 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


        echo '<select name="dropdown" style="width:150px;">';

        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<option value="'.$r['ManufacturerName'].'">'.$r['ManufacturerName'].'</option>'; 
        }

        echo '</select>';
    ?>
    </td></tr>
```

If you want to add it next-to it just add another column to this row and fill the other rows with colspan='2'

```
            <form action="SubmitProduct.php" method="post">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td><td colspan='2'><input type="text" name="Name" required /><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product Desription</td><td colspan='2'><input type="text" name="Product_Desription" required /><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product Price</td><td colspan='2'><input type="text" name="ProductPrice" required /><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product Image</td><td colspan='2'><input type="text" name="ProductImage" required /><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Manufacturer</td><td><input type="" name="" required /><br></td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            include 'db_connection.php';

            $conn = OpenCon();

            echo "Connected Successfully";



            $query = "SELECT * FROM Manufacturer WHERE 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


            echo '<select name="dropdown" style="width:150px;">';

            while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo '<option value="'.$r['ManufacturerName'].'">'.$r['ManufacturerName'].'</option>'; 
            }
    </td>
</tr>
```